# Using Custom Template Tag Inside Built in tags of Django

Tags: django, templatetags

I have created a simple tag as below.

```
 @register.simple_tag(takes_context=True,name="calculate_billamount")
       def calculate_billamount(quantity,unitprice):    
          return (quantity * unitprice)
```

```
     {% for order_detail in order_details %}
       {% if order_detail.orderid == order %}    
           <tr>
                <td>{{order_detail.productid.productname}}</td>
                <td>{{order_detail.unitprice}}</td>
                <td>{{order_detail.quantity}}</td>   
                <td>{% calculate_billamount quantity=5 unitprice=4 %} </td>                                     

                <td>{{billamount}}</td>
         </tr>
     {% endif %}               
    {% endfor %}
```

This is just multiplying 2 numbers and returning the result.

I am trying to use above simple tag inside a FOR and IF as shown below.

I am getting below error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3F7M.png)

when i try this individually, i am not getting any error i.e. it is working fine.

```
        <div>
        {% calculate_billamount quantity=5 unitprice=4 %}
    </div>
```

Is there any restriction, that we cant use Custom Simple Template tags inside django built in template tags like for and if?

Thanking you.

Comment: Do you need a template tag though? Why can't you just make `billamount` as a property on the OrderDetail model?

Answer (score 0):

## First:

I am agree with Sri Vidya, i dont see `{% load custom_tags %}` before using `calculate_billamount`, this is one error.

```
 {% load custom_tags_with_calculate_billamount %}
 {% for order_detail in order_details %}
   {% if order_detail.orderid == order %}    
            <-- any staff -->
            {% calculate_billamount quantity=5 unitprice=4 %}
   {% endif %}               
{% endfor %}
```

don't forget. {% calculate_billamount quantity=5 unitprice=4 %} will render it directly, without wariables assessment. I mean - you dont have `billamount` variable here.

## Second. ***AS*** - syntax:

You can use `{% calculate_billamount quantity=5 unitprice=4 as billamount %}`
In this case you add a variable `billamount` in context. But it will be not rendered automatically, you should do it yourself:

```
 {% for order_detail in order_details %}
   {% if order_detail.orderid == order %}    
       <-- any staff -->
       {% calculate_billamount quantity=5 unitprice=4 as billamount %}
       {{billamount}}
   {% endif %}               
{% endfor %}
```

## Third. *Takes context=True*

Your code simply not works. `takes_context=true` add context of template as a first attribut.

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True,name="calculate_billamount")
def calculate_billamount(context, quantity, unitprice):    
   return (quantity * unitprice)
```

read more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-custom-template-tags-inclusion-tags

## Forth:

For two attributes you can define filter:

```
@register.filter
def calculate_billamount(quantity, unitprice):    
  return (quantity * unitprice)
```

After you can use it in template:

```
{{ quantity|calculate_billamount:unitprice }}
```

read more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters

## Fifth. YAGNY:

I believe - you made all overcomplicated. Simply write in template:

```
{{ quantity * unitprice }}
```

Of corse, in my answer i skip multiple other questions, like: why not change context in template_tag, why using custom template_tags is a bad practice, and many other things. And i am totally agree with comments from @McPherson: it seems, like **billamount** should be as a *calculated property* of any **bill**.

Answer (score -1):

{% load custom_tags %} needs to be placed in both html pages.

My Scenario :

First.html -> is using {%show_orders%} template tag which is displaying results in Second.html with the help of Inclusiontag.

Now when I try to use "Calculate_billamount" custom tag in second.html, it was giving an error. So i had to put {% load custom_tags %} in Second.html too.

Thank you all.

Comment: in my answer i describe, why only {% load custom_tags %} don't give you wanted result. Your tag is wrong written.